# выделить цветом слово внутри ячейки Excel, слова которые нужно найти и выделить предварительно нужно вписать в отдельный столбик(красный,зеленый,сини

Tags: excel

я простой пользователь, мне нужна помощь в следующем вопросе. в Excel я создаю файл в котором есть текст и цифры, мне нужно чтобы некоторые слова в тексте были выделены красным, зеленым и синим цветом (только слова внутри ячейки не весь текст). я хотел бы чтобы в определенной колонке я мог добавлять все слова которые должны быть выделены красным цветом, в соседней колонке другой список слов которые будут выделяться зеленым цветом и третий столбик - сюда добавляю слова которые в основном тексте будут выделяться синим цветом.

то есть:

создать три столбика (колонки) куда буду добавлять нужные мне слова
на основании п.1 в основном тексте слова из списков будут выделяться определенным цветом
Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Comment: Откуда берутся эти выделенные слова? Как они будут расположены? По одному в ячейке?

Comment: Решить эту задачу можно с помощью VBA. Советую попробовать записать макрос и посмотреть, как получить доступ к цвету текста ячейки.

Comment: Глеб, объясните пожалуйста подробнее как создать такой макрос? может где то есть инструкция как создавать макросы для vba

меня даже устроит чтобы определенные слова выделялись автоматически на этой странице в Excel, к примеру также как определенные слова выделяются разными цветами в коде у программистов

Comment: Для начинающих: надо сначала правильно вопрос задавать - с примером размещения данных и примером результата. Желательно "живой" пример, в файле. А вообще, подобный вопрос - это задача для фриланса. Да, нужно писать код.

Comment: опыта программирования у меня нет 

мне всего лишь нужно:
1. условие 
слова вписать в определенные столбики например,
в столбце А (красный цвет) мама, папа, сестра 
в столбце В (зеленый цвет) машина, дом, велосипед
в столбце Е (синий цвет) яблоко, виноград, персик,, груша

2. условие
чтобы именно эти слова (если они присутствуют) внутри ячейки были выделены соответствующим цветом

Comment: Не воспринимайте, как наезд... Но. Не умеете водить - нанимаете такси. Не умеете кран прикрутить - нанимаете сантехника. Написать код для решения Вашей задачи - не сверхусилия, но и время для этого нужно. Да, вполне возможно, кому-то будет не влом потренироваться. И в этом случае сможете получить решение и здесь, без похода по фриланс-площадкам. === Предлагаю другой подход, при котором больше вероятности получить решение. В VBA работать с заливкой труднее, чем со значениями. Вариант: отмечать в соседнем столбце наличие слов со списков. Например, цифрами 1, 2, 3; список слов-совпадений...

Comment: спасибо за вашу помощь, напишу vikttur_.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот макрос, который раскрашивает слова в активной ячейке. Он даже меньше, чем комментарии к вашему вопросу.

```
Sub ColorizeWords()
  Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer, l As Integer
  Dim w As String, m As Integer, c() As Variant
  Dim lj As Long, mj As Long
  c = Array(0, -16776961, -11489280, -4165632)
  mj = Columns(1).Rows.Count
  For i = 1 To 3
    lj = Cells(1, i).End(xlDown).Row
    If lj < mj Then
      For j = 2 To lj
        w = " " & Cells(j, i) & " "
        m = Len(w)
        k = 1
        l = InStr(k, ActiveCell, w)
        While l > 0
          ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=l + 1, Length:=m - 2).Font.Color = c(i)
          k = l + m
          l = InStr(k, ActiveCell, w)
        Wend
      Next
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для макроса слово - это последовательность символов за исключением пробела, ограниченная пробелами. Поэтому макрос не найдёт слова в начале и в конце текста, где нет пробела с одной из строн; он не найдёт слова, ограниченные знаками препинания и другими символами. Над усовершенствованием макроса в этом плане вы можете подумать самостоятельно.

Усовершенствовал макрос. Цвета с верхней левой ячеки, произвольное количество, заголовки должны быть раскрашены в нужный цвет, обрабатывает все выделенные ячейки.

```
Sub ColorizeWords()
  Dim c As Integer, r As Integer, i As Integer, m As Integer
  Dim w As String, cc As Range, color As Long
  Dim lr As Long, mr As Long, mc As Long
  mr = Columns(1).Rows.Count
  mc = Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
  If mc = Rows(1).Columns.Count Then mc = 1
  For Each cc In Selection.Cells
    For c = 1 To mc
      color = Cells(1, c).Font.color
      lr = Cells(1, c).End(xlDown).Row
      If lr < mr Then
        For r = 2 To lr
          w = " " & Cells(r, c) & " "
          m = Len(w)
          i = InStr(cc, w)
          While i > 0
            cc.Characters(Start:=i + 1, Length:=m - 2).Font.color = color
            i = InStr(i + m, ActiveCell, w)
          Wend
        Next
      End If
    Next
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: спасибо большое за потраченное на меня время, я не программист, поэтому постараюсь самостоятельно поискать куда это вставить и поэкспериментирую 
если будут вопросы - напишу вам еще раз

Comment: В Excel нажимаете Alt+F11 - появляется Microsoft Visual Basic for Application. Вставляете новый модуль (Insert-->Module), а в него копируете этот код. Потом выделяете ячейку с текстом, нажимаете  Alt+F8 и запускаете макрос ColorizeWords.

Comment: спасибо большое, работает

Comment: спасибо большое за внимательность

Comment: @rotabor вопрос, который вы задали насчет вычленения слов из текста (правильного определения границ слов) - это довольно сложная задача для VBA. Вы в своем решении считаете границей пробелы. Но как быть со случаями, когда слово в начале или конце текста или после слова запятая?

Comment: @АлексейР вы предложили работоспособное решение с использованием регулярных выражений как один из вариантов. Я написал в своём ответе о способе выборки слов из строки. Поскольку в вопросе никаких требований на этот счёт нет, то я не ставил перед собой задачу реализовать поиск слов в естественном языке. Если бы такое потребовалось, я бы другим вариантом искал бы подстроки, а потом проверял спереди начало строки или пробел, а сзади конец строки, пробел или знаки препинания `InStr(".,?! и т. д", следущий_символ_после_слова)`.

Answer (score 0):

Решение на базе регулярных выражений. На тестовых примерах корректно отрабатывает границы слов, которые могут быть отделены друг от друга не только пробелами, но и знаками препинания, небуквенными символами. Казалось бы, поставил `\b` вокруг подстроки и все дела. Но VBA RegEx не так [как хотелось бы] определяет границы слов для русских букв и не понимает просмотра назад, поэтому пришлось немного нагородить.

```
Option Explicit

Sub PaintText()
    If IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Range("A1")) Then Exit Sub ' если в "таблице цветных подстрок" пусто, то сразу выходим
    ActiveCell.Font.color = vbBlack
    Dim txt, cl, substr, len_sub, color, RegEx, res, match
    
    Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With RegEx
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .MultiLine = True
    End With
    
    txt = ActiveCell    'вносим текст в переменную, чтобы минимизировать количество операций чтения ячейки
    For Each cl In ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion ' забираем связный диапазон, содержащий A1
        substr = cl.Text ' забирает из ячейки видимый текст, даже текст ошибок типа #ДЕЛ/0!
        len_sub = Len(substr)
        If len_sub Then
            color = cl.Font.color
            RegEx.Pattern = "(?:[^\wа-яА-ЯёЁ]|^)(" & substr & ")(?=[^\wа-яА-ЯёЁ]|$)"
            Set res = RegEx.Execute(txt)
            If res.Count > 0 Then
                For Each match In res
                    ActiveCell.Characters(match.firstindex + 1 + IIf(match.firstindex = 0, 0, 1), len_sub).Font.color = color
                Next
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо большое за внимательность

Comment: :-(  А если cl пустая,и вправду бесконечный цикл? Ведь никто же не обещал, что количество слов для каждого цвета будет одинаковое. Ну, и нахождение подстрок, которые не обязательно будут словом.

Comment: @rotabor в моей модели одна строка и каждая ячейка содержит свою подстроку и свой цвет. Пустых не должно быть на входе, они отсекутся. Если делать в несколько строк, то да, нужно сделать проверку на пустоту.

Comment: Мужики - я в этом диалоге ничего не могу добавить или прокомментировать потому как уровень у меня всего лишь позволяет скопировать и вставить, то что Вы разработали.

Comment: Если посоветуете какой нибудь источник где можно почитать о том как создавать МАКРОС(ы), чтобы было понятно для простых людей, я бы с удовольствием прочитал.
В итоге я хотел бы сделать КНИГУ но не в Word, а в Excel -книга в которую из разных книг соберу материал (скопирую), наверное вручную буду копировать текст и картинки (схемы), а если возникнет вопрос зачем создавать книгу в Excel? ответ: чтобы там через МАКРОС(ы) сделать быстрый поиск нужных строк/текста. Например, делаю запрос "линии поддержки" у меня отображается НЕ вся книга, а только те строки где содержатся слова "линии поддержки".

Comment: В Word вы можете решить свою задачу теми же самыми МАКРОСАМИ! А так вы себе хорошую задачу придумали, много всего можно освоить, её решая.

Comment: https://riptutorial.com/ebook/excel-vba https://sci.mu.edu.iq/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Microsoft-Excel-Vba-Programming-For-Dummies-2nd-Edition-Book.pdf https://books.goalkicker.com/ExcelVBABook/ https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-articles/ https://moonexcel.com.ua/main_ru https://www.mrexcel.com/board/ - подобных ресурсов очень много, и находить их легко.